# C function returns different value on python DLL

Tags: python, c

I Just now started to tinker with C dll's and python, so naturally made a quick function on a DLL to see if it worked, and compared it with the same definition on python.

(Also tested on C btw)
This is the C code

```
#include <math.h>
__declspec(dllexport) float speedy_sqrt(float num, float speedFactor) {
        double n, n2, xF;
        if (num == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        n = num/2;
        n2 = n + 1;
        while (fabs(n - n2) > speedFactor*n){
            xF = num/n;
            n2 = n;
            n = (n2 + xF) / 2;
        }
        return n;
}
```

Same concept on python

```
    def speedySqrt(num, speedFactor=0.1):
        if num == 0:
            return 0
        n = num/2
        n2 = n + 1
        while (abs(n - n2) > speedFactor*n):
            xF = num/n
            n2 = n
            n = (n2 + xF) / 2
        return n
```

So, when I tested the C function with (9,1) on compiler, the output was 4.5 (correct), same as the python version.

Now, when i tested the dll form on python side by side to the already existing one, the results were different.

(C function was returning a random seeming large number.)
`348144795` - C | `4.5` - python

I imported it with `ctypes`, here is the test code:

```
def start():
    l = cdll.LoadLibrary('./mods/speedy.dll')
    print(l.speedy_sqrt(9, 1), QuickMaths.speedySqrt(9, 1)) # error when using float params
start()
```

I don't know what is happening since all the code was tested previously on their independent processes and went well. Bad use of ctypes maybe?

Comment: Do you use ctypes anywhere to tell python what the types are?  You might just be passing integers without promoting to floats, and misinterpreting the return value.

Comment: Not exactly. no

Comment: ctypes documentation says “all types but integers, strings, and bytes” must be wrapped in their corresponding ctypes type.  So if you want to pass floats you need to use c_float.  And set restype to c_float

Comment: You should read the ctypes docs a bit more then.  DLL’s don’t include any type information (like a header file does) only the function name, so you have to specify it on the python side, otherwise it just assumes you’re using ints everywhere, which is of course wrong.

Comment: Do i need to change it for the return value as well?

Comment: Yes; looks like use QuickMaths.speedySqrt.restype = c_float or similar should do the trick.  (I’m not an expert on cdll/ctypes, just looking through the docs here. someone might help you rewrite it, but this should get you started)

Comment: alright, thank you!